# How to add partial correlations to DAG's edges using the `pcalg`, `igraph`, and `gRim` packages in `R`

Tags: r, igraph, directed-acyclic-graphs

Using an example from the `pcalg` package itself, I am wondering whether and how one can add partial correlations to edges in a DAG? Here is an example:

```
require(pcalg)
require(igraph)
require(gRim)

data(gmG)
n <- nrow(gmG8$x)
V <- colnames(gmG8$x) # labels aka node names
## estimate CPDAG
pc.fit <- pc(suffStat=list(C=cor(gmG8$x), n=n),
    indepTest=gaussCItest, ## indep.test: partial correlations
    alpha=0.01, labels=V, verbose=FALSE)

gr = as(pc.fit@graph, 'igraph')
plot.igraph(gr, layout=layout_in_circle,
    vertex.color='grey',
    vertex.shape='circle', vertex.size=25,
    vertex.label.cex=0.6, vertex.label.color='blue',
    edge.arrow.size=0.5)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you want to add the value from `pc.fit@pMax` for the relevant edge?

Comment: I believe that pMax is the maximum p-value, not the correlation. The independence test is based on partial correlations. I was thinking that it would be nicely informative to add these values to respective edges (that passed the test, so to say).

Comment: right of course. The results of the test do not seem to be returned by pc. There may be a way where you could iterate through the graph edges and run the independent test manually e.g. I think run gaussCItest in this case. . As an akt, perhaps depending on the test you could invert the p-values . e.g. for `gaussCItest` use `qnorm`

Comment: Could you give a code example? As an alternative, how about if I just calculate partial correlations and put those in? Thanks @user20650!

Answer (score 0):

One way to get the partial correlations is to use pcalg's `pcorOrder()`. Given the above example, something like this:

```
corMatrix <- cor(gmG8$x)
pcormtx = matrix(0, nrow=8, ncol=8)
allVars = 1:8
for (i in seq(from=1, to=7, by=1)) {
    for (j in seq(from=i+1, to=8, by=1)) {
        S = allVars[!allVars %in% c(i,j)]
        pcormtx[j,i] = pcorOrder(i, j, S, corMatrix)
    }
}
pcormtx = round(pcormtx, 3)
pcormtx[upper.tri(pcormtx, diag=TRUE)] = NA
print(pcormtx, na.print='')
#        [,1]   [,2]   [,3]   [,4]  [,5]   [,6]  [,7] [,8]
# [1,]                                                    
# [2,]  0.201                                             
# [3,] -0.011  0.610                                      
# [4,] -0.006 -0.002  0.004                               
# [5,] -0.213  0.106 -0.009  0.006                        
# [6,]  0.412 -0.008 -0.020  0.010 0.129                  
# [7,]  0.003  0.001  0.003 -0.015 0.002  0.346           
# [8,]  0.218 -0.012  0.016 -0.019 0.695 -0.009 0.001
```